# unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index while passing parameter as well as using wildcard in query

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, data-science

i am facing an issue in python where i am using a query and i am passing some params in it :

```
query =   select * from %s where xyz like 'abc%'
  query %(tablename)
```

here it gives me an error . Can anyone help in this

Comment: None of that looks like correct python syntax. Maybe start with an easier example?

Comment: this is just an example , its an existing project . The requirement is like this that i have to pass the table name as a parameter and i have % as a wildcard too . it gives me an error when i remove the % after abc it works but i need the %

Answer (score 1):

It looks like python is interpreting the % as a printf-like format character. Try using %%?

```
query =   select * from %s where xyz like 'abc%%'
```

Comment: or try escaping the % with / so /%